# Using multiple Python versions: Can IDLE be configured to see *.py3 / *.py2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python, and was curious about this idea. Since there are differences between Python 2.x and 3.x, could IDLE be modified (in a configuration or settings file) to recognize and compile files with a .py3 or .py2 extension? Also, is this something that would difficult to implement, or better yet, is this worth the effort to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not worth the effort. There are better ways to support both Python 2 and Python 3. See http://python3porting.com/, in particular http://python3porting.com/strategies.html.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about Idle, but the preferred way to have your files determine the python version to use would be not to have different file extensions, but to use a "shebang" line, like `#! /usr/bin/python3`. To make this work on windows as well as linux, there is the new [Python Launcher for Windows](http://blog.python.org/2011/07/python-launcher-for-windows_11.html) (described in [pep 397](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/))

Comment: That looks more like a "bangshe" to me.  (I tried to edit it, but SO won't accept edits less than 6 characters. ;)